# Unable to stop / restart iptables

Tags: linux, debian, firewall, iptables

Im really struggling with this issue of iptables refusing to stop / restart.

When i try to stop it it will output this message:

```
xgsv01:/# service iptables stop
iptables v1.4.8: Couldn't load match `-tcp':/lib/xtables/libipt_-tcp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
iptables v1.4.8: Couldn't load match `-tcp':/lib/xtables/libipt_-tcp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
Iptables firewall is up 'date'.
xgsv01:/#
```

---

I have researched many other users had a similar problems and they were related to once of the rulesin the chains having incorrectly specified tcp parameter but this seems to be not the case.

These are my rules:

```
xgsv01:/# iptables -t filter -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N LOGGING
-N fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 23700 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 23600 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 23500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3784 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 3784 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 23600 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tap+ -j ACCEPT
xgsv01:/#
```

I was searching if i have somewhere specified '-tcp' but without luck. The other thing is i guess iptables should reference /lib/xtables/libipt_tcp.so and i am missing this shared library as well...

```
xgsv01:/lib/xtables# find libipt_tcp.so
find: `libipt_tcp.so': No such file or directory
xgsv01:/lib/xtables#
```

Could you please somebody give me an advice or any other help? Im not an experienced Linux user - just some basics.
iptables version 1.4.8
    Linux version 2.6.32-5-686 (Debian 2.6.32-46) (dannf@debian.org) (gcc version 4.3.5 (Debian 4.3.5-4) ) #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 09:49:36 UTC 2012

Other rules:

```
xgsv01:/# iptables -t nat -S 
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT 
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT 
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT 
-A PREROUTING -s 147.175.0.0/16 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 92.240.237.87:23600 
xgsv01:/# man iptables 
xgsv01:/# iptables -t mangle -S 
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT 
-P INPUT ACCEPT 
-P FORWARD ACCEPT 
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT 
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT 
xgsv01:/# iptables -t raw -S 
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT 
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Comment: Is the `-tcp` in the NAT table maybe?

Comment: I have searched all the remaining tables but no luck:

Comment: These are the table rules:

    xgsv01:/# iptables -t nat -S
    -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
    -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
    -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    -A PREROUTING -s 147.175.0.0/16 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 92.240.237.87:23600
    xgsv01:/# man iptables
    xgsv01:/# iptables -t mangle -S
    -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
    -P INPUT ACCEPT
    -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
    xgsv01:/# iptables -t raw -S
    -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
    -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    xgsv01:/#

Comment: A little bit of cleanup: (1) your `find` syntax is wrong; (2) `libipt_tcp.so` library doesn't exist at all (not only on your system). You can safely remove these remarks from your question.

Comment: Instead of separate commands, could you edit and show the full output of `iptables-save`?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean? I just typed the command and that what you see in the post is the actual output... Thanks for the notification regarding the find command and shared object. I will try suggestions posted earlier and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to remove all your iptables config and apply the default ones?

Will you be able to restart iptables service gracefully then?

Take a look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/easy-setup-of-iptables-on-your-new-linux-server.html) for few iptables how-to's, it may help too.